# my header is null angular 6 in http post Error

Tags: javascript, angular, http

Hello I am using Angular 6 and I am trying to a http post.

I know the user is allowing Multiple origins with the

```
    <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/> </customHeaders>
```

my code:

```
     let data = this.http.post(
            this.base_url + this.walletControllerSubUrl +"login", 
           {username: "exampleuser", password: "Pass123!"}
          );
          data.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
            console.log("data" + data);
            return data;
```

I always get the error:

> " Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8100, *', but only one is allowed"

but I also now noticed that my header seems to go null

```
    headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
```

what would cause the header to be null when I not even passing any
header?

There is another application but in AngularJS, running well with the same post.

what would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers using CORS will attempt to send a pre-flight request, usually an OPTIONS call. It expects a response from the server with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response; however, compliance standards restrict this response header to contain only ***one*** url in that header (or the wildcard *).

The server you are hitting appears to be sending multiple values.

You'll need to fix the server response to only send back the wildcard or make your request through a proxy.

EDIT: 
Your headers are null because headers are not sent with the pre-flight request unless the withCredentials requestOptions are used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error recently, just add `proxy.json` file that contains a json that defines real proxy to server and add it to start script